# How do you move to a new page when web scraping with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Below I have code that pulls the records off craigslist. Everything works great but I need to be able to go to the next set of records and repeat the same process but being new to programming I am stuck. From looking at the page code it looks like I should be clicking the arrow button contained in the span here until it contains no href:

```
<a href="/search/syp?s=120" class="button next" title="next page">next &gt; </a>
```

I was thinking that maybe this was a loop within a loop but I suppose this could be a try/except situation too. Does that sound right? How would you implement that?

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://nh.craigslist.org/d/computer-parts/search/syp")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")

listings = soup.find_all('li', class_= "result-row")

base_url = 'https://nh.craigslist.org/d/computer-parts/search/'

next_url = soup.find_all('a', class_= "button next")


dates = []
titles = []
prices = []
hoods = []

while base_url !=
    for listing in listings:
        datar = listing.find('time', {'class': ["result-date"]}).text
        dates.append(datar)

        title = listing.find('a', {'class': ["result-title"]}).text
        titles.append(title)

        try:
            price = listing.find('span', {'class': "result-price"}).text
            prices.append(price)
        except:
            prices.append('missing')

        try:
            hood = listing.find('span', {'class': "result-hood"}).text
            hoods.append(hood)
        except:
            hoods.append('missing')

#write the lists to a dataframe
listings_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates, 'Titles' : titles, 'Price' : prices, 'Location' : hoods})

 #write to a file
listings_df.to_csv("craigslist_listings.csv")
```

Comment: The request for each page should be made within the loop. You need ensure that `find_all` is returning at most 1 element each time for the next page anchor element. Then the next iteration of the loop should request the url set to the `href` property of that element. Terminate the loop when either this element can no longer be found or the `href` property is an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each page you crawl you can find the next url to crawl and add it to a list.

This is how I would do it, without changing your code too much. I added some comments so you understand what's happening, but leave me a comment if you need any extra explanation:

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


base_url = 'https://nh.craigslist.org/d/computer-parts/search/syp'
base_search_url = 'https://nh.craigslist.org'
urls = []
urls.append(base_url)
dates = []
titles = []
prices = []
hoods = []

while len(urls) > 0: # while we have urls to crawl
    print(urls)
    url = urls.pop(0) # removes the first element from the list of urls
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    next_url = soup.find('a', class_= "button next") # finds the next urls to crawl
    if next_url: # if it's not an empty string
        urls.append(base_search_url + next_url['href']) # adds next url to crawl to the list of urls to crawl

    listings = soup.find_all('li', class_= "result-row") # get all current url listings
    # this is your code unchanged
    for listing in listings:
        datar = listing.find('time', {'class': ["result-date"]}).text
        dates.append(datar)

        title = listing.find('a', {'class': ["result-title"]}).text
        titles.append(title)

        try:
            price = listing.find('span', {'class': "result-price"}).text
            prices.append(price)
        except:
            prices.append('missing')

        try:
            hood = listing.find('span', {'class': "result-hood"}).text
            hoods.append(hood)
        except:
            hoods.append('missing')

#write the lists to a dataframe
listings_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates, 'Titles' : titles, 'Price' : prices, 'Location' : hoods})

 #write to a file
listings_df.to_csv("craigslist_listings.csv")
```

**Edit:** You are also forgetting to import `BeautifulSoup` in your code, which I added in my response
**Edit2:** You only need to find the first instance of the next button, as the page can (and in this case it does) have more that one next button.
**Edit3:** For this to crawl computer parts, `base_url` should be changed to the one present in this code

Comment: Great! Took some time to go through the code but I am pretty sure I understand everything going on. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to how to access the "next" button, but this may be a solution to your problem. When I've webscraped in the past I use the URLs of each page to loop through search results.
On craiglist, when you click "next page" the URL changes. There's usually a pattern to this change you can take advantage of. I didn't have to long a look but it looks like the second page of craigslist is: https://nh.craigslist.org/search/syp?s=120, and the third is https://nh.craigslist.org/search/syp?s=240. It looks like that final part of the URL changes by 120 each time.
You could create a list of multiples of 120, and then build a for loop to add this value on to the end of each URL. 
Then you have your current for loop nested in this for loop.

Comment: That's an approach I had thought about but decided that if a query ended having 100 pages, for example, I probably wouldn't want to be making a list although if the increment is consistent amount then I could iterate by 120 until i no results are returned.....I think.